# Rending a separate page dynamically using django and htmx

Tags: django, htmx

Am working on a simple task app using Django and HTMX. I want when a user clicks on a button in the navbar to add a task, the add task page should be displayed dynamically without causing a page reload.
Yes the task page gets displayed dynamically but when i try to reload my page Some content of the page gets lost.
Checkout below the code snippets

navbar.html

```
{% load static %}

<div class="flex justify-between pt-10 pb-3">
    <div class="w-6/12">
        <div class="font-bold text-gray-700 text-2xl" style="cursor: pointer;">Task Manager</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/12 text-gray-500" style="cursor: pointer;">Home</div>
    <div class="w-1/12 text-gray-500" style="cursor: pointer;">Pending</div>
    <div class="w-1/12 text-gray-500" style="cursor: pointer;">Complete</div>
    <div class="w-1/12 text-gray-500" style="cursor: pointer;">Pricing</div>
    <div class="w-1/12 text-gray-500">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
        <a role="button" class="bg-blue-700 rounded text-white font-bold text-sm px-4 py-1" href="{% url "create_todo" %}" hx-get="{% url "create_todo" %}" hx-push-url="true" hx-target="#main">Add Task</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/12 text-gray-500">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
            <img src="{% static 'images/me.jpg' %}" alt="Profile" srcset="" class="rounded-full w-12 h-12">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

home.html

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}

{% block title %}Home Board{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    {% include "./navbar.html" %}
    <div class="px-20" id="main">
        <div class="flex justify-between">
            <h3 class="mt-5 text-center text-xl text-gray-500 font-bold my-8">Today's Tasks</h3>
            <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
                <button class="bg-blue-700 rounded text-white font-bold text-sm px-4 py-1">View Calendar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
                <button class="bg-blue-700 rounded text-white font-bold text-sm px-4 py-1">All</button>
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-center items-center ml-4">
                <button class="bg-blue-700 rounded text-white font-bold text-sm px-4 py-1">Completed</button>
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-center items-center ml-4">
                <button class="bg-blue-700 rounded text-white font-bold text-sm px-4 py-1">Incomplete</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="all-tasks">
            {% include "./todo-list.html" %}
        </div>
        <div id="completed-tasks">
        </div>
        <div id="incomplete-tasks">
        </div>
    </div>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
<div>
    
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
def create_todo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST.get("title")
        description = request.POST.get("description")
        due_date = request.POST.get("due_date")
        todo = Todo.objects.create(title=title, description=description, due_date=due_date)
        # todo.save()

        todos = Todo.objects.all().order_by("-id")
        context = {
            "todos": todos,
        }
        return render(request, "todo/todo-list.html", context)
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "todo/add_task.html")
```

add_task.html

```
<div class="flex justify-center">
    <div class="w-full">New Task</div>
    <div>
        <label for="title">Task Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
    </div>
</div>
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home")
]

htmx_patterns = [
    path("clear_message/", views.clear_message, name="clear_message"),
    path("create_todo/", views.create_todo, name="create_todo"),
    path("delete_todo/<int:pk>", views.delete_todo, name="delete_todo"),
    path("mark_todo/<int:pk>", views.mark_todo, name="mark_todo"),
    path("todo_details/<int:pk>", views.todo_details, name="todo_details")
]

urlpatterns += htmx_patterns
```

When the page is rendered, it looks like below[Image showing the add_task page rendered dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPyal.png)

When i try to reload the page, the contents of the page change to
[image of the add_task page after me trying to reload it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDgVo.png)

I thought after reloading the page, the contents on it would remain the same

Comment: Remove href from the link as it's not needed when using hx-get. Second - make sure you handle the add task endpoint on from the backend routing, if you want to be able to refresh the page (unless you're already doing it then please provide more context: urls defs + what url are the images coming from) tx

Comment: I literally want the pages to be displayed dynamically without page reload, but also when a user tries to force a reload, the contents and how it is displayed shouldnt change. as i explained in the question.

Comment: Below are my urls

''' urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home")
]

htmx_patterns = [
    path("clear_message/", views.clear_message, name="clear_message"),
    path("create_todo/", views.create_todo, name="create_todo"),
    path("delete_todo/<int:pk>", views.delete_todo, name="delete_todo"),
    path("mark_todo/<int:pk>", views.mark_todo, name="mark_todo"),
    path("todo_details/<int:pk>", views.todo_details, name="todo_details")
]

urlpatterns += htmx_patterns'''

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve it is to provide entire html template when "non-htmx" request is done.

So in your view, check if request is triggered by htmx and if not, use different template (one that includes add_task.html and extends from base.html)

```
elif request.method == "GET":
    if request.headers.get("HX-Request") == "true":
        return render(request, "todo/add_task.html")
    
    return render(request, "todo/add_task_with_base.html")
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro, it has worked out for me, i still got alot more questions about django and htmx. I appreciate

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this answer, if it helped. Also look into django-htmx python package, it's a must-have when working with django.